# Hardware security module

Tags: c#, dongle, hardware-security-module

Does anyone know aobut HSMs supporting C#? I googled and got 3 vendors. But there's no information given on there sites about whether they support C# and I would like to know the prices also.

The three HSM vendors:

- AEP Keyper
- Safenet Luna
- Thales nShield

Any suggestions appreciated!

Regards,
Supriya

Answer (score 4):

An additional vendor that is missing on your list above is Utimaco, make sure to visit http://hsm.utimaco.com - they also offer a HSM-simulator to test the integration which can be downloaded from their website after registering.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at [Sentinel HASP](http://www.safenet-inc.com/aladdin-content/sentinel-hasp/) a while ago.

They provide a comprehensive SDK, and support .NET languages. The SDK is free and comes with 1 USB hardware key.

If you phone/email they will give you advice on pricing. it depends on the volume you are using.

Answer (score 1):

C# can use Windows's Cryptographic Service Providers. Any HSM with Windows support will supply a CSP module, and so you'll be able to use any of these from C# - that's unlikely to be an issue.

I suspect you'll have to contact the individual suppliers for pricing.